# How to import tsfel module without raise error?

Tags: python, signal-processing, import-module

I use the `tsfel` package to extract features from signals. I try to implement a personalized feature and I have read the documentation (https://tsfel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/descriptions/personal.html). I have followed the steps exactly but when i try to run the second step (i.e. Add the new feature to features.json) it raises an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tsfel.features_utils'`.

Here is a simple example of code

```
import numpy as np
# from tsfel.add_personal_features import add_feature_json

@set_domain("domain", "statistical")
def range(signal):
    range = np.max(signal) - np.min(signal)
    return range
```

The error is: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tsfel.features_utils'`

How should I import the module?

Comment: Did you # your line2 import on purpose ?

Comment: is tsfel correctly installed? What version of tsfel are you using?

Comment: @LSeu yes i did it on purpose. Of course my code wouldn't get there because of error.

Comment: @apoorvakamath I think so. I just followed the instructions and used 'pip install tsfel'. The version is tsfel 1.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

For the version 0.1.6, you may do as follows

```
from tsfel.feature_extraction.features_utils import set_domain
```

You can also confirm it from the [github](https://github.com/fraunhoferportugal/tsfel/blob/master/tsfel/feature_extraction/features_utils.py)
[image]